# Read page URL in XML? Or use PHP within an XML file

Tags: php, xml, url

I have a flash element (I know, but please don't) with a settings.xml file.

One of the values in the XML file depends on the URL, so rather than having multiple instances of the flash folder, I want to do the following:

```
value="<?php $rest = substr(<?php echo curPageURL(); ?>, -2, -1) ?>"
```

I tried that in vain, but as you probably already knew, that won't work.

So I either need a way to write that in XML, or to allow that line of PHP within the XML file.

```
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
        $pageURL. = "s";
    }
    $pageURL. = "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL. = $ _SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL. = $ _SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two things for this to work:

1. Your server would need to be configured to parse XML files as PHP files. If you're using Apache, that's something in your configuration similar to this:

   ```
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .xml
   ```
2. You'd need to use valid PHP syntax, like so:

   ```
   value="<?php echo substr( curPageURL(), -2, -1); ?>"
   ```

   Assuming that `curPageURL()` is a function defined in PHP.

Finally, you should ensure that the `short_open_tag` directive is set to `Off` in your `php.ini` configuration, or else PHP will throw syntax errors when it encounters XML opening tags, e.g. `<?xml`. This can be done in .htaccess with something similar to

```
php_value short_open_tag Off
```