# PHP not parsing XML file

Tags: php, xml, parsing

My original issues solved: [Read page URL in XML? Or use PHP within an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143640/read-page-url-in-xml-or-use-php-within-an-xml-file), have lead to a new one.

I have a flash element in a webpage, whose .swf calls upon a settings.xml file for certain values.

One of the values must be url dependant - it needs to show the value (0-2) that is the second-last character of URL (before trailing /).

So I have a PHP function, `curPageURL()`, which grabs the URL, and slices out the correct character, this is tested working.

The line in XML reads:

```
value="<?php echo substr( curPageURL(), -2, 1); ?>"
```

And .htaccess contains:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .xml
```

Yet, when I view the source at /settings.xml, the line reads off `<?php` unaltered, and the flash doesn't display. If I substitute the PHP for the value which it does evaluate too, it works fine. So for some reason it isn't parsing.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you're getting raw php code, then you haven't done your settings correctly... have you confirmed the .htaccess is being parsed?

Comment: How would I go about that? (Apologies, pretty new to PHP/server stuff)

Comment: simplest way is to type some garbage into the .htaccess, save it, then hit your .xml url again. if you get an internal server error, then Apache is at least LOOKING at the .htaccess

Comment: Ah, well when I added `php_value ...`, it commented it out and said for security reasons I needed to use a separate php.ini file. So I assume that shows it's at least looking at it?

Comment: btw, x-http-php5s is for PHP **SOURCE**. it outputs the specified file type with the php code nicely colorized. try just `x-httpd-php5`, which is the actual php interpreter.

Comment: I now have `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .xml`, XML still shows raw PHP.

Comment: @MarcB, Any other ideas? I've been experimenting - but whatever I try, the XML file either cuts out when it reaches the PHP line, or at best displays all but shows raw PHP. Thanks for your patience thus far with   such a newbie..

Comment: Simple workaround: just name the file .php. Since it's being fetched via http, you simply output the text/xml content-type header and flash won't care if it's http://example.com/blah.php or /blah.xml or /foo.bar. it just cares about the actual content and the content-header

Comment: Hmm. I renamed to .php, and now viewing source cuts out at the PHP line again, flash still not displaying. Do I need to put 's' back in .htaccess or ammend the .swf for different extension or something?

Comment: if it cuts out at the php line, then check the server error logs for any php errors.

Comment: Oh I just checked the error log - it says the function isn't defined, yet it works when I call it on a webpage? Edit - just saw your comment, noticed the log file as I was refreshing.

Comment: I should probably add that the curPageURL() function is defined in the page template, directly after the header, before the page content (which includes the flash files).

Comment: Defining the function in the same directory as settings.xml has stopped producing errors. But raw PHP still shows, and there're warning messages where the _flash_ should be. Warnings call out problems in the simplexml_load_file() function, in the plugin.php that pulls in the flash. If I change back from .xml to .php, the warning messages go, but XML cuts out at PHP line again, and flash still doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, it forced PHP to interpred XML as PHP script:

```html
<Files ~ "\.(xml)$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```